# video is not streaming when piped to a middle stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I would like to create a basic video streaming server with usage statistics, using `node.js`,
the video source is a local file. The streaming works as expected with this:

`fs.createReadStream("file.mp4").pipe(res);`

But I would like to get some usage statistics, so I added a `passThrough` stream,

`const stats = new PassThrough();`

for the statistics I will add some code to the `stats` stream data event like this
`//stats.on('data',(chunk)=> { });`

But now **the video is not streaming any more** when I pipe it to the stats stream

`fs.createReadStream("file.mp4").pipe(stats).pipe(res);`

can you tell me please what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Still can't figure out how to put the stats middle stream and receive the video stream on res, although, one possible solution is to move the stats events listeners to the readStream like so:

```
const { createReadStream, stat } = require("fs");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const fileInfo = promisify(stat);
const { size } = await fileInfo(filePath);

const { range } = req.headers;
      let start = 0;
      let end = size - 1;

      if (range) {

        start = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")[0];
        start = parseInt(start, 10);
        end = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")[1];
        end = end ? parseInt(end, 10) : size - 1;

        res.writeHead(206, {
          "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
          "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
          "Content-Length": end - start + 1,
          "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
        });
        logUpdate("range:", range);

      } else {

        res.writeHeader(200, {
          "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
          "Content-Length": size,
        });
      }

      createReadStream(filePath, { start, end })
        .on("data", dataEventHandler)
        .on("error", errorEventHandler)
        .on("close", closeEventHandler)
        .on("end", endEventHandler)
        .pipe(res);

dataEventHandler = (chunk) => {
  total += chunk.length;
  logUpdate("bytes: ", total);
};
```